# Терминал распознавания лиц iVMS-4200 не подключается к базе

Tags: mysql, sql, консоль

Я подключил устройство распознавания лиц DS-K1T341AMF к программному обеспечению iVMS-4200. Я хотел подключить базу данных mysql к окну экспорта в базу данных iVMS-4200. Я правильно ввел всю информацию, которую необходимо ввести для подключения к базе данных в окне программы. Я получаю сообщение об ошибке сохранения, когда нажимаю кнопку «Сохранить» с включенной кнопкой «Принять базу данных». Я запустил базу данных в программе "MAMP".
[image: iVMS-4200-1]
[image: iVMS-4200-2]
*Окно подключения к базе данных программы iVMS-4200*
**(Third-party database)**

- database type: MySQL
- Configuration file: C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\lib\libmysql.dll
- Server IP adress: 127.0.0.1
- port: 3306
- Database name: imron
- User name: root
- User Password: root
- Table name: nik

**База сделана в phpmyadmin**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Mar 20, 2023 at 06:23 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.24
-- PHP Version: 8.0.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `imron`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `nik`
--

CREATE TABLE `nik` (
  `a1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a2` datetime NOT NULL,
  `a3` date NOT NULL,
  `a4` time NOT NULL,
  `a5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `a6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `a7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `a8` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `a9` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Приведите хотя скриншоты, как пытались. Тогда будет хотя бы минимальный шанс, что кто-то поможет

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос и попытался сделать его более понятным для вас, ребята.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, iVMS-4200 и MySQL установлены на одном и том же компьютере, верно? Если да - проверяйте, выполняется ли подключение к MySQL с использованием штатного клиента командной строки mysql.exe и указанных параметров подключения. *Configuration file: C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\lib\libmysql.dll* - а это вообще что? как может быть конфигурационным файлом динамическая библиотека?

Comment: Я установил виртуальный сервер "MAMP" и программное обеспечение iVMS-4200 на один компьютер. Виртуальный сервер "MAMP" имеет MySQL версии 5.7. Я попытался подключиться к этому серверу в Python. Соединение прошло успешно. Но в программе iVMS всегда есть ошибка. «Файл конфигурации: C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\lib\libmysql.dll» — iVMS-4200 попросил выбрать этот файл.

Comment: такая же беда
пробовал и sql и mysql и разные версии IVMS